# Service reference only async and completed methods are shown. why?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, service-reference

I have defined new method in IFoo:

```
[OperationContract]
List<string> GetChatSubjects(string siteId);
```

and defined this method in FooReferece.svc.cs

```
public List<string> GetChatSubjects(string siteId)
{
  ...  
  return List<string>;
}
```

When I try to get this reference only

- void GetChatSubjectsAsync();
- EventHandler GetChatSubjectsCompleted();

methods are shown in my service reference. I need GetChatSubjects() method which return List. I need method's itself. Why only listed methods are shown above?

By the way, my project in Silverlight.

Comment: You can easily get `List<string>` using `GetChatSubjectAsync` method. Just use `await` keyword (don't forget to use `async` on your method declaration as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WEll because Silverlight supports only async calls. The reason is that silverlight runs on the browser UI thread. and sync call will block the UI till the callback is received.